# Correct error or transform code to recursive function to evaluate matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

I need a function that separates all the "islands" or regions of a matrix that are formed by 1s. In my example it works correctly, but there are some "special" cases where it fails (as in the example case).

**How can I correct this error? or transform this function into a recursive function. Let the for travel through the matrix and in the position that is a 1, call the recursive function and evaluate all the points around it.**

```js
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

var contFilas = matrix.length;
var contColumnas = matrix[0].length;
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sz = 20;
var regions = [];
var regionCollection = [];

canvas.width = sz * contColumnas;
canvas.height = sz * contColumnas;
ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

for (var y = 0; y < contFilas; y++) {
    var regionline = [];
    regions.push(regionline);

    for (var x = 0; x < contColumnas; x++) {
        var pixelRegion = 0;
        regionline[x] = 0;
       


        if (matrix[y][x] === 1) {
            // check previous row
            if (y) {
                if (matrix[y - 1][x]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x];
                } else if (x && matrix[y - 1][x - 1]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x - 1];
                } else if (x + 1 < contColumnas && matrix[y - 1][x + 1]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x + 1];
                } 
            }

            // check current row
            if (x && matrix[y][x - 1]) {
                pixelRegion = regions[y][x - 1];
            }

            // if not connected, start a new region
            if (!pixelRegion) {
                regionCollection.push([]);
                pixelRegion = regionCollection.length;
            }
            // remember region
            regionline[x] = pixelRegion;
            regionCollection[pixelRegion - 1].push([x, y]);

            // paint it
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(x * sz + 1, y * sz + 1, sz - 2, sz - 2);
        }


        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText(pixelRegion, x * sz + 8, y * sz + 13);

    }
}
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(regionCollection);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>getUserMedia</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas></canvas>
 <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In the example**, region 2 and 3 must be only one (region 2). That is, **there will be 2 different regions. What is my error in the code? How can I correct it?**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you're trying to do this in one pass of the array, which is not really possible (depending on what exactly you count as "one pass").

The simplest algorithm is probably to loop through the array and where you see a `1` perform a flood-fill operation. Any pixel hit by the flood fill would be stored in a region and then ignored by the rest of your loop. Flood fill is computationally fairly slow, but it's well understood and there is a lot of code out there for it.

Given you already have this code, though, I expect you'll end up with a faster solution just by taking the `regionCollection` object you have and checking which regions touch. If any do, combine them. It will be less readable and probably more code than using flood-fills though, so it depends what you want to optimise for.